# NodeBacked entity NPE - entityState is null

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I've got a sample project which uses Spring Data Neo4j's advanced mapping using aspectj.  It's failing in a test with NullPointerException due to the entityState attribute being null at the time when the entity is being persisted.

I can also replicate this when the server itself is spun up and I execute:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Test",  "lastName" : "Person" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

The project is at https://github.com/dhallam/spring-data-neo4j-demo and the Travis build with the logs is at https://travis-ci.org/dhallam/spring-data-neo4j-demo/builds/22538972.

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something or there is a bug that would require me to raise a JIRA issue.

Any ideas?  Many thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

Versions: Java v1.7; SDNeo4j v3.1.0.M1; SDRest v2.1.0.M1; Neo4j v2.0.1; Jetty v9.0.5.v20130815; AspectJ v1.7.4

Tried adding @JsonIgnoreProperties to the Person (@NodeEntity)from Michael's comment below and it's still failing.  The bit of code that is failing is when I run:

```
Person p = new Person();
// setters ...
p.persist();
```

The `persist()` calls

```
public <T extends NodeBacked> T NodeBacked.persist() {
    return (T)this.entityState.persist();
}
```

but `entityState` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  The `Neo4jConfig` class previously extended the `Neo4jConfiguration` class.  With the introduction of aspects, that superclass needed to be updated to be `Neo4jAspectConfiguration` to provide the additional `neo4jRelationshipBacking` and `neo4jNodeBacking` beans.

I've updated the github reference project at https://github.com/dhallam/spring-data-neo4j-demo and the build is passing.

Answer (score 1):

Which versions do you use?

You can use @JsonIgnore for the entityState attribute.

See: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/110063-unable-to-convert-nodeentity-object-to-json-with-jackson

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"entityState", "nodeId", "persistentState", "relationshipTo", "template"})
```

Comment: Still failing for the same reason, unfortunately.  I've updated the question in **Edit 1**.  Many thanks for your help.