# Switching from Simple to Advanced Mapping: entityStateFactory not set, not creating accessors for class

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.x and I'm trying to switch to using Advanced Mapping Mode. I've setup my pom.xml to contain the necessary  aspectj-maven-plugin stuff and I can see that the code compiles fine, with ajc doing its thing.

However, as soon as I try to save a @NodeEntity, I get the following error:

[ERROR] Neo4jNodeBacking: entityStateFactory not set, not creating accessors for class com.example.graph.Type

I'm not doing anything special in my SpringConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration; what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need to use Neo4jAspectConfiguration instead of Neo4jConfiguration in your Configuration object (SpringConfig in my case). I could not find this anywhere in the docs actually. See also:

[NodeBacked entity NPE - entityState is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945171/nodebacked-entity-npe-entitystate-is-null)